# material for acoustic reflection?

Tags: acoustics, reflection, system, sound-design

I'm trying to find some cheap material to make acoustic reflectors out of. From what I hear the most important thing is that the material be stiff, however from my research stiffness (measured in GPA or bulk modules or elastic modules) has a pretty broad range. so I was wondering if anyone knew:

At what gpa does a material have to have to qualify as a good acoustic reflector?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you do some research into absorption coefficients and look for materials with a low absorption coefficient.  If you need further detail I suggest you look at the Master Handbook of Acoustics: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Master-Handbook-Acoustics-Alton-Everest/dp/0071603328